# why getOpenSessions() returning 0

Tags: java, websocket

I am trying to create a chatroom with java and tomcat.  Here `id` is the chat room id. every time i connect a new user but the `getOpenSessions()` function return 0. 
Every client is connecting with the following `uri`

```
ws://localhost:8080/websocket_implementation/chat/123
```

The following is the code for opening connection.

```
@OnOpen
        public void open(final Session session, @PathParam("id") final String id) {
    System.out.println(session.getUserProperties());

            session.getUserProperties().put("id", id);

            System.out.println(session.getOpenSessions().size());
        }
```

Any idea, what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue(Tomcat 7, Oracle Java8), it works on windows on localhost but when deployed on the remote machine with Ubuntu installed getOpenSessions() returns 0.

If no one knows how to fix it, all open sessions should be managed manually like this for example:

```
private static final Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());
```

and add sessions to the set onOpen and remove onСlose respectively

Answer (score 0):

```
Amazon EC2 Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

When the app is deployed on Tomcat 7, getOpenSessions() returns 0

when deployed on jetty 9 getOpenSessions() works as expected.
```

Seems like a tomcat problem.